# Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: found at wrong position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zsh, rbenv

I try to check my `rbenv` problem with using its `rbenv-doctor` command ;

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

I get this;

```
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: found at wrong position 
  The directory `/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims' is present in PATH, but is listed too late.
  The Ruby version found in `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin' will have precedence. Please reorder your PATH.

Checking `rbenv install' support: /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20210510)
Counting installed Ruby versions: 5 versions
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

I want to highlight this one;

```
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: found at wrong position
```

The result says `Please reorder your PATH.`. How I do this ???

---

(Update) This is `rbenv` things in my `./zshrc` file

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/krb5/sbin:$PATH"

if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/luajit-openresty/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ncurses/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Just go to your `~/.zshrc` file and edit the PATH string.

Comment: @red_menace, can you look at my `./zshrc` file that I update in my post.

Comment: never mind, I delete and reinstall again `oh-my-zsh` and `./zshrc`. Then same for rbenv.

Comment: Note that in your update, all those are being added to the beginning of your PATH.

Answer (score 4):

From [the `rbenv` README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-path):

> **Understanding PATH**
>
> When you run a command like `ruby` or `rake`, your operating system
> searches through a list of directories to find an executable file with
> that name. This list of directories lives in an environment variable
> called `PATH`, with each directory in the list separated by a colon:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
> ```
>
> Directories in `PATH` are searched from left to right, so a matching
> executable in a directory at the beginning of the list takes
> precedence over another one at the end. In this example, the
> `/usr/local/bin` directory will be searched first, then `/usr/bin`,
> then `/bin`.
>
> **Understanding Shims**
>
> `rbenv` works by inserting a directory of shims at the front of your
> PATH:
>
> ```
> ~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
> ```

Check where you have added `~/.rbenv/shims` to the `PATH` (probably in a file like `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.zshrc`?), and ensure you are adding it to the **START** of the `PATH`, not the end.

To see the full contents of the `$PATH` variable, you can run:

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: can you look at my `./zshrc` file that I update in my post.

Comment: never mind, I delete and reinstall again `oh-my-zsh` and `./zshrc`. Then same for rbenv.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified instructions for MacOS users:

```
sudo vim ~/.zshrc
```

Add this at the end of file:

```
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
```

Write and Quit vim editor

```
:wq
```

Verify setup:

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

Expected output:

```
Checking for `rbenv' in PATH: /usr/local/bin/rbenv
Checking for rbenv shims in PATH: OK
Checking `rbenv install' support: /usr/local/bin/rbenv-install (ruby-build 20220910.1)
Counting installed Ruby versions: none
There aren't any Ruby versions installed under `/Users/username/.rbenv/versions'.
You can install Ruby versions like so: rbenv install 3.1.2
Checking RubyGems settings: OK
Auditing installed plugins: OK
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` variable is essentially an ordered list of directories, separated by `:`. When you enter an executable's file name, e.g., `ruby`, those directories are searched one by one, in order, to find a binary file named `ruby`.

So when you have multiple `ruby` files in your `PATH` directories, the ordering of the `PATH` directories matters. You need to ensure the desired directory appears before its 'competitors' in `PATH`. This is as easy as:

```
desired_dir=/some/dir
export PATH="${desired_dir}:${PATH}"
```

You can put the above snippet at the end of `.zshrc`, to ensure that it is the very last code that your shell runs.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks, I already put the snippet in my `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because someone installed ruby prior to using `rbenv`, which is fine. You don't need to uninstall anything. You can fix this by doing the following:

1. Open your profile, usually `~/.zshrc`
2. Find the first instance where `export PATH` is called. It's okay if its not called anywhere.
3. Type this into your `.zshrc` file, but change the directory to your own `export PATH="/Users/janac/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`

To know if you did everything right, run

`curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`

and verify there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

> The Ruby version found in `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin' will have precedence.

Looks like you installed ruby using Homebrew. If you plan to use rbenv instead, I suggest that you uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

For thosse it's not wortking just simply try this command

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/main/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```